# Using Moq with SQLiteConnection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, nunit, moq

I am trying to understand how to use Moq with SQLiteConnection.
The problem is that since I am quite new to Moq and I have not found any relevant tutorial on my problem.

I would like some tips on how to use it.

The error:

```
    SetUp : Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.
    Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
    SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32.SQLitePlatformWin32
    System.String
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyInstance(Type proxyType, List`1 proxyArguments, Type classToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments)
   at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type mockType, ICallInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments)
   at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__2()
   at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject()
   at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
   at Silje.Synchronization.Test.AktoerSynchronizationTest.SetUp()
```

The code sample:

```
        private SQLiteConnection _sqLiteConnection;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            Mock<SQLiteConnection> 
            mockSQLiteconnection = new Mock<SQLiteConnection>(MockBehavior.Loose, 
                 new SQLitePlatformWin32(),
                 "TestDb");
            var t = mockSQLiteconnection.Object; // fails!!!
        }
```

Another exception occurs when I do this:

The error:

```
SetUp : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32.SQLiteApiWin32Internal' threw an exception.
  ----> System.Exception : Failed to load native sqlite library
```

Codesample:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _aktoerListeDto = MockAktoerListe();
    Mock<SQLiteConnection> mockSQLiteconnection = new Mock<SQLiteConnection>(
        new SQLitePlatformWin32(),
        "TestDb",
        It.IsAny<bool>(),
        It.IsAny<IBlobSerializer>(),
        It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, TableMapping>>(),
        It.IsAny<IDictionary<Type, string>>(),
        It.IsAny<IContractResolver>());
    var t = mockSQLiteconnection.Object;
}
```

Comment: SQLite.NET's SQLiteConnection class *doesn't* have a constructor with only two parameters. You need to provide values for the optional parameters as well, either by passing values explicitly or by using the "wildcard" syntac, eg `It.IsAny<bool>()`, `It.IsAny<IBlobSerializer>()`,  etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However I get another error where it give me " System.Exception : Failed to load native sqlite library" on SQLitePlatformWin32. I have added It.IsAny on the other arguments for SQLiteConnection

Comment: What parameters did you pass and what is the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: added to the edited post. :P

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos (your initial comment) There is absolutely no use for `It.IsAny<>` in that context. That only make sense insinde expression trees to be interpreted by Moq's `Setup` method etc. In your context, `It.IsAny<bool>()` etc. will just be evaluated to `false` (the `default(bool)`), and `(IBlobSerializer)null` (the `default(IBlobSerializer)`), respectively. So bad advice.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen the point is that Moq doesn't recognize optional parameters so all optional parameters must be filled.

Comment: @Khiem-KimHoXuan the new exception means that the SQLite dll  is missing from your test project. It should be added just as it was added to the main project (eg with a NuGet package)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK, that is a good point. But use actual values such as `false`, `null` etc. in the constructor argument list.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tight coupling with `SQLiteConnection`.
I think you should try mocking an "abstraction" instead of the "concrete" `SQLiteConnection` class. Check if an interface like `ISQLiteConnection` exists(or can be introduced) and go and ahead mock that instead. It would decouple your system under test.

Comment: could you give an example, yaar?